# How can we set the Title of Google Search Result snippet using meta tags of site in Asp.Net?

Tags: asp.net, metadata, meta-tags

**How to set the title of Google search result snippet using meta tags in Asp.Net website ?**

Answer (score 0):

The meta tags are a  important part of the HTML code of your web page.Search engines performs crawling on them.

Usually they include a concise summary of the web page content and you should include your relevant keywords in them.

Most meta tags are included within the 'header' code of a website. 
The most important tags are the

Find More Info [here](https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/)

**1.Title**

**2.Description**

**3.keyword's**

**4.Robot tags**

so it is important to Optimize your meta tags to improve the searchability of your site.